# MongoDB virtual Schema using split

Tags: mongodb

**Why this does not work???.**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  courses: [{ type: String, ref: 'Course' }]
});

/* Returns the student's first name, which we will define
 * to be everything up to the first space in the student's name.
 * For instance, "William Bruce Bailey" -> "William" */
schema.virtual('firstName').get(function(name) {
    var split = name.split(' ');
  return split[0];
});
```

**Error**: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: Ran your code,didn't give me any error.

Comment: still don't work :/

Comment: Same error, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

try to put "this" before name so your code will look like this

```
schema.virtual('firstName').get(function(name) {
  var split = this.name.split(' ');
  return split[0];
});
```